# Beginner - How to place info in tables - CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, create-table

I have to make a database and i'm already stuck with something. I want to make a database where i will have 5 tables. User, complaint, missing, wanted and stolen objects.

So I want to make a database where a user puts his info, then file a complaint. The user has the choice about 3 complaint subjects: missing, wanted or stolen object. So after the complaint, it should be placed in the right table.

I'm not sure on how to place the right info in the right table, I'm new with mySQL..

Here is my database for the moment:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    sexe VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    age INT(3) NOT NULL,
    birthplace VARCHAR(50),
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE complaint (
    complaint_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user INT NOT NULL,
    complaint_sort VARCHAR(16),
    title VARCHAR(150),
    name VARCHAR(15),
    date_complaint,
    place VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (complaint_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES Gebruiker (gebruiker_id)
);

CREATE TABLE missing (
    missing_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    complaint_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (missing_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (complaint_id)
        REFERENCES Complaint (complaint_id)
);

CREATE TABLE wanted (
    wanted_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    complaint_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (wanted_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (complaint_id)
        REFERENCES Complaint (complaint_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Stolen_objects (
    Stolen_objects_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    complaint_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (stolen_objects_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (complaint_id)
        REFERENCES Complaint (complaint_id)
);
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the `INSERT` keyword?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create three tables for complaint types - missing, wanted, stolen_objects.

Instead of creating three tables just add a flag in **complaint** table for `complaintType` with `ENUM` as data type with values like missing, wanted, stolenObjects.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE USER ( 
    user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    sexe VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
    age INT(3) NOT NULL, 
    birthplace VARCHAR(50), 
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(50), 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id) 
); 

CREATE TABLE complaint ( 
    complaint_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    USER INT NOT NULL, 
    complaintType ENUM('Missing','Wanted','stolenObjects') NOT NULL, 
    complaint_sort VARCHAR(16), 
    title VARCHAR(150), 
    NAME VARCHAR(15), 
    date_complaint DATETIME, 
    place VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    description VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (complaint_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USER (user_id) 
);
```

Comment: but `stolen_objects` has an additional column, and maybe other tables will have unique columns as well.

Comment: @barmar In OP's question,there is no extra columns in all three tables. AND if there are 2-3 extra columns then it is good manage in these table. No need to create extra table for each complaint type.